# Http request works from Postman, Python but not from C# error 404

Tags: c#, http

When I attempt an webrequest using c# I get error 404, the same request works in both python and Post man. Here is my c# code:

```
public void GetTorrentsTest3()
{
    var url = "http://oneom.is/ep";
    var request = WebRequest.Create(url);
    request.Method = "GET";

    using var webResponse = request.GetResponse();
    using var webStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream();

    using var reader = new StreamReader(webStream);
    var data = reader.ReadToEnd();

    Console.WriteLine(data);
}
```

Here the same request in PostMan:

[image]

Any ideas ?

Comment: in Postman you use https in your c# code just http.

Comment: I have tried both

Comment: The site seems to check the UserAgent header and the WebRequest class does not send one of its own. Add such a header yourself like `request.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent, "myLovelyUserAgent");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not anything to do with your code. That specific URL seem to be upset that you are not providing a User Agent header.

I'd suggest that all you need do is set your user agent, for which I refer you to [How to set User Agent with System.Net.WebRequest in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33659663/how-to-set-user-agent-with-system-net-webrequest-in-c-sharp)